# What are the regulatory requirements that will halt the sale of the Mac Pro in Europe?

Tags: hardware, mac-pro

As noted today on MacRumors [Apple to Halt Mac Pro Sales in Europe Effective March 1 Over Regulatory Requirements](http://www.macrumors.com/2013/01/31/apple-to-halt-mac-pro-sales-in-europe-effective-march-1-over-regulatory-requirements/) However they fail to mention the specifics of why it fails to meet "Amendment 1 of regulation IEC 60950-1, Second Edition" ?

> Apple today issued a notice to European distributors indicating that it will halt sales of the Mac Pro in Europe and select other countries as of March 1 due to new regulatory requirements going into effect on that date. The move will affect all European Union countries, as well as EU candidate countries and the four European Free Trade Association countries: Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway, and Switzerland.
>
> > As of March 1, 2013, Apple will no longer sell Mac Pro in EU, EU candidate and EFTA countries because these systems are not compliant with Amendment 1 of regulation IEC 60950-1, Second Edition which becomes effective on this date. Apple resellers can continue to sell any remaining inventory of Mac Pro after March 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further updates:

> Update 10:24 AM: [Macworld UK](http://www.macworld.co.uk/mac/news/?newsid=3423807) has even more on the issue:
>   "The Mac Pro met the previous standards prior to the amendment 1 addition. Obviously it's a very safe and very reliable product," added the company.
>
> At issue are the large fans within the Mac Pro. Since they are unprotected, it would be possible to touch the fan blades.
>
> "The new requirements necessitate fan guards and some increased protection on the ports on the electrical system," explained Apple.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [summary of the changes by TÜV Rheinland](http://www.tuv.com/en/greater_china/about_us_cn/regulations_standard_updates/latest_regulations_en/latest_regulation_content_en_118211.html):

> EN 60950-1:2006/A1:2010 includes the following significant changes from EN 60950-1:2006/A11:2009.
>
> - **Modified requirements for bridging resistors (1.5.7.1 and 1.5.7.2)**
> - **Additional requirements for VDR (1.5.9.4)**
> - Modified marking requirement for equipment with multiple MAINS SUPPLY connections (1.7.1.1)
> - Modified compliance criteria for LPS (2.5 c)
> - Additional and modified requirements for safety interlocks (2.8.4)
> - **Modified requirements for minimum creepage distances (Table 2N)**
> - Additional requirements for rack-mounted equipment that should comply with Annex DD (4.2.1)
> - Additional requirements for rotating solid media (4.2.11)
> - Additional requirements for UV radiation (4.3.13.3 & 4.3.13.4)
> - Modified requirement for LEDs whose compliance standard is changed to IEC 62471 (4.3.13.5)
> - **Additional requirements for protection against moving fan blades (4.4.5)**
> - **Additional requirements for evaluation of IC current limiters (Annex CC)**
> - Additional requirements for the mounting of rack-mounted equipment (Annex DD)
> - Additional requirements for household and home/office document/media shredders (Annex EE)